# Configure Asterisk as SIP outbound proxy (as a SIP server relay)

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, sip

I just installed an Asterisk and i would like to configure Asterisk as a SIP server relay.

**I already have a SIP server but this one doesn't accept directly Web Sockets (wss) connections.**

[image]

The purpose is to have a web client which use SIPJS library : (http://sipjs.com/guides/user-agent-construction/) and which will be able to make a register on sipserver A.

How do I configure `sip.js` and `extension.conf` file on asterisk to do that ?

Comment: did you solved this ? I have same situation and I appreciate if you share your experience and result

Answer (score 5):

This likely isn't the answer that you want, but, [Asterisk is not a SIP proxy](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+not-proxy). It's technically a B2BUA (back-to-back user agent).

In short, that means Asterisk is always a kind-of end-point on the call.

You might try using [Kamailio](http://www.kamailio.org/w/features/) which can be used as a stateless relay to act as a SIP proxy, and it's rather good at it.

However, you may be able to B2BUA the call if you can both:

A: Create a trunk from Asterisk to "SIP Server A"

B: Create a client connection from SIP.js to Asterisk. [Documentation available for SIP.js specifically for this](http://sipjs.com/guides/server-configuration/asterisk/).

In which case, once the call comes inbound to Asterisk from the SIP.js client, you can bridge calls using the `Dial` application in Asterisk to make a call to "sip server a"

For example, `sip.conf`:

```
[sipjs]
context=inbound_sipjs
; ...and the rest from sip.js documentation

[sipservera]
context=inbound_sipserver
; rest as required with your sip server
```

Then, in your `extensions.conf`, assuming an inbound call from SIP.js client:

```
[inbound_sipjs]

exten => _X.,1,Noop(Call from SIP.js)
same =>      n,Dial(SIP/sipservera/${EXTEN})
same =>      n,Hangup()
```

Comment: FYI, the "Documentation available for SIP.js..." link is broken as it requires https instead of http. I tried to modify it, but because of the 6-chars-required rules, I couldn't.